# Condicional abierta por X segundos

Tags: python

Me gustaría que si una condicional tarda mucho tiempo abierta se cierre a los 10 segundos. Ejemplo:

```
X = 1
if x == 1:
    print("Está abierta")
```

Como saben, se quedará para siempre así, pero, me gustaría que en 10 segundos se cierre. No puede ser un loop que haga iteraciones, me gustaría que la indicación sea desde la misma condicional. Ejemplo:

If x == 1 and timer < 10:

¿Qué tengo que poner? ¿Me ayudan?

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: a que te refieres con *abierta*?, una condicional solo evalúa la expresión y ya, continua con la ejecución del programa, las condiciones no son ciclos.

Comment: Tienes razon. Tengo un loop y dentro una condicional, pero, no quiero que ese print de esa condicional siempre se mantenga imprimiendo, quiero que se detenga si pasan  X segundos.

Comment: entonces tenes un loop y queres que el loop pare... lo que estas preguntando no tiene sentido...

Comment: Me disculpo por mi ignorancia, ya vere como lo resuelvo. Saludos y gracias por tomar el tiempo en responder o intentar ayudarme.

Comment: Mejor pon el código completo, por que así como muestras no se entiende nada de lo que quieres

Comment: No tenes porque disculparte.. Lo raro es que digas que no puede ser un loop, cuando el codigo es secuencial, se ejecuta una instruccion y ahi termina su ejecucion.. no se esta repitiendo el if infinitamente, ni el print, salvo que ese codigo este dentro de una iteracion....

Answer (score 0):

Dado que lo que quieres es que la condición también evalué un tiempo solo tenemos que agregar una expresión mas, para eso hacemos uso del modulo `time`.

```py
import time

inicio = time.time()#iniciamos el tiempo
while True:#ciclo infinito
    x = 1
    fin = time.time()#el valor que tenga hasta ahora
    tiempo = fin-inicio#calculamos el tiempo
    if x == 1 and tiempo<4:#verificamos
        print("Holas")
    else:
        break #si es mayor al tiempo salimos
```